# Excluding records where criteria meets

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have a set of records where we identify several items connected to a customer. 
My dilemma is that if a customer has both items then I would like to exclude that customer.

If they only have one specific item then I want to include it.
I will be using this code to create a view so i'm trying to find the best way. I could try `Row_number()` to identify different records, but I'm not sure that would be ideal in this situation.

Example data table:

```
Customer | ItemID | value1 | Value2
   A         12       35       0
   B         12       35       0
   C         13       0        25
   C         12       0        25
   D         18       225       12
```

Desired Output:

```
 Customer | ItemID | value1 | Value2
   A         12       35       0
   B         12       35       0
```

This is what I have so far:

```
select Customer, ItemID, Value1, Value2
from Table1 
where itemID = 12
```

This would give me customer `'C'`, which I don't want.

Comment: Don't be shy.  What specific items are you talking about?

Comment: Do you want to exclude customer C because they have both ItemID 12 & 13? Am I correct in thinking that the values in the Value1 and Value2 columns are irrelevant when it come to deciding whether to include or exclude a customer from the results?

Comment: Why not customer D? D also has only 1 kind of item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want customers who have `itemid = 12` but **not** `itemid = 13` you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from tablename t
where itemid = 12
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where customer = t.customer
  and itemid = 13
)
```

If you want customers who have `itemid = 12` and **not** any other `itemid`:

```
select * from tablename t
where itemid = 12
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where customer = t.customer
  and itemid <> 12
)
```

or:

```
select * from tablename
where customer in (
  select customer from tablename
  group by customer
  having min(itemid) = 12 and max(itemid) = 12 
)
```

Comment: Probably you want `itemid != 12` rather than `itemid = 13`

Comment: Probably, or not! Maybe I will include a 2nd query.

Comment: Yeah, my interpretation is the same as in CGul's answer but it's not 100% clear

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help!! This was very helpful. I'm sorry my description wasn't very clear, but you were able to give me exactly what i needed! I have never used "not Exists" but this was the perfect place for it! Thank you @forpas

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to clarify your question but, as I understand it, you're looking to return the all rows where:

1) A customer has a particular item (i.e. Item ID 12, which excludes customer D)

and

(2) They only have one item in total, which excludes customer C since they have two items.

If that is the case, then here's what I've got:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE ItemID == '12' AND 
      Customer in (
                   SELECT Customer
                   FROM Table1
                   GROUP BY Customer
                   HAVING Count(Customer) = 1
                  )
```

Edit: I clarified my interpretation of OP's question. I also tested my solution on SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b5f1f/2/0) and updated the WHERE clause accordingly.

Comment: If you made an SQLFiddle it will always improve an answer by including a link to it.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Didn't know I could do that.